# How to perform $out in an aggregation in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, aggregation, out

I looked for documentation of how to perform $out in an aggregation but I didn't find.

This is my query:

```
Top.aggregate([
  {$sort: {created: -1}},
  {$group: {_id:'$location', title:{$push: '$title'}}},
  {$project: {location: '$location', mostRecentTitle: '$title'}},
  {$out: "aggr_out"}
]).exec(function(err, docs) {  console.log(docs); console.log(err) });
```

Schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  location: {type: String},
  title: {type: String},
  created: {type: Number, default: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)}
})
```

It might to be compatible with mongodb 3.0.x

Comment: This saved my day as I was trying to save a Mongoose aggregate into a MongoDB collection. It's a welcome approach where Mongoose AggregationCursor does not seem to work. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3327

Answer (score 2):

I checked the database and it seems to create a new collection something like 'aggr_out' with the entries. I'm considering it as solved.

Comment: Top.aggregate([
  {$sort: {created: -1}},
  {$group: {_id:'$location', title:{$push: '$title'}}},
  {$project: {location: '$location', mostRecentTitle: '$title'}},
  {$out: "aggr_out"}
])

Answer (score 1):

Most of queries might be done by using `node-mongodb-native` on `Mongoose`.
For an `out` option the result would be the same.

Also it will create a collection for you automatically.

```
Top.collection.aggregate([
      {$sort: {created: -1}},
      {$group: {_id:'$location', title:{$push: '$title'}}},
      {$project: {location: '$location', mostRecentTitle: '$title'}},
      {$out: "aggr_out"}
    ],
    function(err) {  
        if (err) console.log("error: ", err) 
        else console.log("the all documents have been written onto aggr_out!") 
    }
);
```