# How to copy all the mongoose Documents from one collection to another in same Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to copy all the documents from one collection to another in same DB. How can I do that?

Schemas are as follows:

```
var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String
});

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);
```

Now to move all the documents:

```
var Object=[];
Kitten.find(function (err, kittens) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    Object=kittens;
    console.log(Object);

    Cat.insertMany(Object, function(error, docs) {
       if (err) return console.error(err);
       Kitten.deleteMany( function (err) {});
    });

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform $out in an aggregation in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333284/how-to-perform-out-in-an-aggregation-in-mongoose)

Comment: You need change `.Find` to `.aggregate` and use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Schemas are as follows:

```
var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  });

  var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  });

  var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);
```

Now to move all the documents

```
var Object=[];
  Kitten.find(function (err, kittens) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    Object=kittens;
    console.log(Object);

    Cat.insertMany(Object, function(error, docs) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  Kitten.deleteMany( function (err) {});
});

  })
```